# localhost and webhost not the same output in PHP

Tags: php, localhost, web-hosting

Sorry I'm beginner in PHP, I would like to ask for help why in localhost I perfect what I want to the process but when I upload it on our webhost it was different output from the process, same in date.

I'm from Philippines (GMT+8).

Example of what I entered in my process:
the Date today in both date input so the status will be NEW - FRESH - ACTIVE
but when I input in webhost side the status will be like DORMANT, WINBACK, INACTIVE.

**Screenshot:**
**Localhost (which is perfect process):**
[image]

**Webhost view (which is not correct):**
[image]

**EDIT: I ADDED hongkong timezone still have problem in process in webhost**
**Here is my code:**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $dateRegistration = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateRegistration']);
    $dateStarted = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateStarted']);
    $dateExpiration = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateExpiration']);
    $accType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['accType']);
    $subsType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subsType']);
    $status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);

    //declartion
    $accType = "NEW";
    $subsType = "FRESH";
    $status = "ACTIVE";
    $color = "<th style=\"color: #cccc00;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    #7f7f00

    //Equation 
    $dateExpiration = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($dateStarted. '+ 30 days'));

    //$dateRegExisting = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($dateRegistration. '+30 days'));


    if (strtotime($dateRegistration)<strtotime('-30 days')) {
        $accType = "EXISTING";
        $subsType = "RENEWAL";
        $color = "<th style=\"color: #7f7f00;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    } 



    if (strtotime($dateStarted)<strtotime('-30 days')) {
        $subsType = "FOR RENEWAL";
        $accType = "EXISTING";
        $status = "INACTIVE";
        $color = "<th style=\"color: red;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }


      if (strtotime($dateStarted)<strtotime('-90 days')) {
        $accType = "DORMANT";
        $subsType = "FOR WINBACK";
        $status = "INACTIVE";
        $color = "<th style=\"color: red;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    }


}


  $date1 = date('Y/m/d');

  echo "<br/>";
  echo "<br/>";
  echo "Today is: ".$date1;


  ?>


  <html>

  <head>

  <title>Add New Subscriber | Customer Information System</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

  <title>Title goes here</title>


 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js">   </script>
<script>

webshims.setOptions('waitReady', false);
webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');

</script>

<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}

#expiration {

color: red;
 }

</style>
</head>

<body>


<form action="" method="POST">

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label><strong>Date of Registration:</strong></label>
<input type="date" id="date" name="dateRegistration" placeholder="Date of Reg">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label><strong>Start of Subscription:</strong></label>
<input type="date" id="date" name="dateStarted" placeholder="Start ">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="hidden" id="expiration" name="dateExpiration" placeholder="Expiration" ></font>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="margin-left: 25em;">
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<table style="margin-left: 7em;">

    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Date of Registration&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Start of Subscription&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Expiration&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Account Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Subscription Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
        echo "<th style=\"color: black;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$dateRegistration."</th>";
        echo "<th style=\"color: black;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$dateStarted."</th>";
        echo "<th style=\"color: black;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$dateExpiration."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>";
        echo $color.''.$accType."</th>";
        echo $color.''.$subsType."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>";
        echo $color.''.$status."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>";

        ?>

    </tr>

 </table>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my own answer, I removed the `mysql_real_escape_string` if no database included.

Answer (score 0):

May be your web host system doesn't set time to the current time, but a time somewhere in the past. You might want to check system time using:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); exit;
```

Put that at very first php line in your code and check if the time match with the current time, then consider change your system time.

Regards,

Comment: but why the system, was not the same process in the localhost? I input past dates but still different output.

Comment: I already added that as you can see there I echo the : `Today is: $date`; 
By the way  I'm from  Philippines (GMT+8).

Comment: Ah, ok, didn't notice that. Really weird situation I have to say. the `$dateStarted` and `$dateRegistration` missing unexpectedly but `$dateExpiration` which derived from `$dateStarted` is appear. Can you var_dump all three date variables?

Comment: Ah, just simply use `var_dump($dateStarted, $dateRegistration, $dateExpiration); ` at the bottom of your php code

Comment: it output NULL NULL NULL.

Comment: Yes, that is. The webserver not receive any input from client. Can you `var_dump($_POST);` and show me the result?